# Query with Content Type

Tags: development, content-type, caml-query, caml

I am trying to get the **ListItems** from a generic List with normal/standard Items in it.

I have following `query`:

```
   <Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
         <Value Type='Computed'>0x01009653DF73CE10F94C8FCF852C8217FAC0</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
   <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
   </ViewFields>
```

I have seen the **Content Type** of the **ListItems** via debugging my **TimerJob** with which I am looping through a List an get the **Content Type** of each **ListItem**.

But as soon as I put it in in a `CAML query` in **CAML Designer 2013** and select my list to execute my query on I get no result returned from `CAML`.

Is there a known issue with the content Types and `CAML` or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with you I am seeing is `<FieldRef Name='ContentType' />`. This should be like `<FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' />`.

You are specifying the ID of Content Type. So you should use the Field name as **`ContentTypeId`** instead of **`ContentType`**

Or else try with specifying Content Type Name instead of Id as shown below

```
<Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
         <Value Type='Computed'>Content Type Name</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
   <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
   </ViewFields>
```

I recently gone through this problem and I got solution as I specified.